# C++ std::Thread program does nothing

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm playing around with the std::Thread class and wrote this small code to test it but it seams that it does nothing actually.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class TestThread
{
  public:
      TestThread();
      ~TestThread();
      void foo();
      void bar();
};

TestThread::TestThread()
{}

TestThread::~TestThread()
{}

void TestThread::foo()
{
  while(true)
    cout << "Thread 1 reporting" << endl;
}

void TestThread::bar()
{
  while(true)
    cout << "Thread 2 reporting" << endl;
}


int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   TestThread test;
   thread t1(&TestThread::foo, &test);
   thread t2(&TestThread::bar, &test);
   t1.join();
   t2.join();
   return 0;
}
```

When I execute this, it basically does nothing. It stops after I start it without printing anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You _cannot_ execute it. It doesn't compile (missing includes and `using namespace`) and it doesn't link (missing constructor and destructor definitions). Other than that, it _does_ do what you want it to do. So, shall we try this again?

Comment: sorry i did not post the whole code i'm not new to C or C++ i'm new to this thread thing and simply did not know i had to use -pthread. adding that made the thing work

Comment: I don't know if I missed somehing, but this code compiles and succeeds verbatim.

Comment: i edited it, i did not add the includes and using namespace so Lightness was not able to compile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments said, you are missing `include` and `using` statements, so it likely that you are executing some other program rather than this one.

Here is a corrected program that will actually compile and run.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using std::thread;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class TestThread
{
  public:
    TestThread() { }
    ~TestThread() { }
    void foo();
    void bar();
};

void TestThread::foo()
{
    while(true)
        cout << "Thread 1 reporting" << endl;
}

void TestThread::bar()
{
    while(true)
        cout << "Thread 2 reporting" << endl;
}


int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    TestThread test;
    thread t1(&TestThread::foo, &test);
    thread t2(&TestThread::bar, &test);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is how you would compile and run it, assuming you put it in a file called `ThreadPlay.cc`.

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread ThreadPlay.cc
./a.out
```

Comment: i did not miss the includes and statements i just copied the relevant parts of the code i thought i was making a mistake using the threads or need to call some other method. but i guess i did not use -pthread while compiling. i tried it again with -pthread and it worked thanks you

Comment: @Tychus, Sometimes the community can be a little harsh when your question talks about running code and you post an example that doesn't compile because it increases the effort (overhead) required to address the actual problem. However, since that was _almost_ the only thing you were missing, I figured you had put in sufficient effort.

Comment: There's nothing "harsh" about it. You _did_ miss the includes and statements and, when they were added, your problem was not reproducible. So, you were wasting our time. This is not "harsh": it is a fact. It's the reason we ask you to produce a [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): it _proves_ that the problem is what you say it is. In this case, it was not. It's not just for us: learning this skill is akin to learning how to debug, which is crucial for your own career. Cheers.

Comment: @merlin2011: Asking people to post on meta for help re-opening silly, non-reproducible questions is irresponsible. I expect more from a 25k user. It didn't just "not compile"; it did not match the question even when made to compile. Please actually try it before commenting.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, That's fair. I've removed that comment. The problem of not including `-pthread` is quite reproducible. The issue was that the OP failed to describe the actual problem correctly.

Comment: @merlin2011: Right, which is downvote-worthy. This is not a charity.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Agreed, but not necessarily close-worthy if the question is edited appropriately to be more specific about the problem. I note though that the question has not been edited appropriately, so I agree that it should not be reopened in its current state.

Comment: @merlin2011: The entire purpose of changing "close" to "on hold" is to indicate that closing it before it's corrected via edit is the correct course of action. There is no reason to leave a question open simply in the far-reaching hope that it _may_ become a reasonable question later. Experience tells most of us that this rarely occurs anyway. Anyway, I appreciate that you now see that. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I was not aware of that history. I only started being heavily active on Stackoverflow in the last two years after that change was put in place. Thank you for that knowledge. :)